# django celery only calls 1 of 2 apply_async task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I need to call the following 2 apply_async tasks:

```
escalate.apply_async((e.id), countdown=3)
escalate.apply_async((e.id), countdown=3)
```

My tasks implementation looks like:

```
@app.task
def escalate(id, group):

      escalation_email, created = EscalationEmail.objects.get_or_create()
      escalation_email.send()

    return 'sup email sent'
```

I run the work with the following command:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=10
```

The problem is that when I look at the worker, only 1 tasks is received and then only 1 succeeds.  Also, only 1 email sends.

It seems that most of the time the second escalate task runs.

How can I ensure that these tasks both fire 100% of the time with reliability?

Comment: How are you calling celery? Try adding --concurrency=2

Comment: @SebastianSmolorz I'm calling the worker with:  celery -A proj worker -l info --concurrency=10 , but it still only runs one of the tasks.  When I spin up two different workers, then it handles both tasks.  The problem remains, what happens if 3 tasks are called, would the 3rd not execute if there are not 2 workers?

Comment: Does the problem only occur when you try to send 2 of the same task? Try writing another dummy task and call it in the same way. BTW you can just use `task.delay()` rather than `task.apply_async()`

Comment: @SebastianSmolorz I will need to send the tasks at different times, one at 30 seconds and one at 5 minutes.  Am I able to set the countdown parameter in the delay() function?

Comment: Sorry, just read the docs, delay is a shortcut to apply_async but it '...does not support execution options'. So what about when you call it from slightly different places in the code with different countdowns? Try to make it work and figure out what it is that's causing the issue. It's really quite hard to say with so little information. This shouldn't be happening but it could be a problem with Celery itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not choose a queue to associate the task with.